# How to expose kubernetes POD's Rest URL to a helm hook?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a use case wherein I have a Rest API running on a POD inside kubernetes cluster, and the helm pre-upgrade hook which runs a k8s Job needs to access Rest API, What is the best way to expose this URL so that helm hook can access it. I do not want to hardcode any Ip.

Comment: You should be able to make a call to the matching Service as usual.  What does your current hook Job look like, and what problems are you running into?

Comment: yes as told by david, you are able to access with servicename and port.
what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: sorry I am novice in kubenetes, but the way I tried was is to give the Ip address and it works, but in production we so many clusters and we would not know ahead what ip they will have, how can I access the URL from a helm hook job in that case

Comment: @JinuMohan Consider getting familiar with [DNS for services and pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). I hope it will resolve most of your questions.

Comment: Thanks @moonkotte , thats exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand it for better experience.

As David Maze and Lucia pointed out in comments, services are accessible by their IPs and URLs based on service names.

This part is covered and well explained in official kubenetes documentation [DNS for services and pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)